# Polymorphism in Haskell data fields

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, field, chess, option-type

I'm trying to learn Haskell by creating a simple Chess game. However, I'm having trouble defining the function that represents a square of the board

```
import Data.Char
type Board = [[Square]]
type Square = Maybe Piece
data Piece = Piece PieceColor PieceType deriving (Show, Eq)
data PieceColor = White | Black deriving (Show, Eq)
data PieceType = King | Queen | Rook | Bishop | Knight | Pawn deriving (Show, Eq)

...    

displaySquare :: Square -> Char
    displaySquare n
        | n == Nothing = ' '
        | n == Just (Piece White _) = displaySquare' n
        | otherwise = toLower (displaySquare' n)
            where
                displaySquare'   (Just (Piece _ King))   = 'K'
                displaySquare'   (Just (Piece _ Queen))  = 'Q'
                displaySquare'   (Just (Piece _ Rook))   = 'R'
                displaySquare'   (Just (Piece _ Bishop)) = 'B'
                displaySquare'   (Just (Piece _ Knight)) = 'N'
                displaySquare'   (Just (Piece _ Pawn))   = 'P'
```

Trying to run GHCI returns the following error:

```
Chess.hs:21:30:
    Found hole ‘_’ with type: PieceType
    Relevant bindings include
      displaySquare' :: Maybe Piece -> Char (bound at Chess.hs:24:13)
      n :: Square (bound at Chess.hs:19:15)
      displaySquare :: Square -> Char (bound at Chess.hs:19:1)
    In the second argument of ‘Piece’, namely ‘_’
    In the first argument of ‘Just’, namely ‘(Piece White _)’
    In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘Just (Piece White _)’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I'm not exactly sure what the error is trying to tell me. If I had to guess, I'd say the problem is defining a data field as a hole '_', since that means the function could take any type as a data field, which obviously conflicts with the type signature given. Is my assumption correct, and how should I go about solving it?

Comment: You tried to use pattern syntax (`_`) in an expression, which would usually result in an error. However, `_` is now a "valid expression" as well, so the compile assumed you knew what you were doing and had intentionally placed the `_` there. In expression syntax, this is called a "typed hole" - basically, it is used for type directed programming, as the compiler spits out all the type information around that binding. The compiler should probably only recognize typed holes if they are enabled... otherwise it should give a parse/syntax error, to avoid confusion like this.

Comment: @user2407038, this confusion is rare, and avoiding it is not worth the inconvenience of making everyone enable an extension to use typed holes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way to write `displaySquare` with pattern matching:

```
displaySquare Nothing = ' '
displaySquare n@(Just (Piece White _)) = displaySquare' n
displaySquare n                        = toLower (displaySquare' n)
  where
    ...your definition of displaySquare'...
```

You are using pattern matching correctly in your definition of `displaySquare'`.

Note how the syntax `n@(Just (Piece White _))` works -- it provides a pattern to match against: `Just White _` and it also sets the variable `n` to the argument passed to the function.

**Update**

As @behzad.nouri mentions in the comments you'll need to put the helper function at the top level.

Another way of writing it to keep the helper function local:

```
displaySquare n =
  case n of
    Nothing              -> ' '
    Just (Piece White _) -> displaySquare' n
    _                    -> toLower (displaySquare' n)
  where
    displaySquare' x = ...
```

In this case `n` is bound to the first argument of `displaySquare` so you don't need to use the `n@...` syntax.

Comment: this will fail to compile as the helper function is not in scope in the 2nd line

Comment: It also throws an error since  `n@(Just White _)` should be `n@(Just (Piece White _)`. However, fixing that and defining the helper function as a regular one worked! Out of curiosity, is there any way to define the helper function so that it remains inside of displaySquare? Googling about helper functions for multiple functions didn't seem to bring anything up.

Comment: Answer works great! Using `case` makes it a lot more readable.

Comment: @NicolásSiplis You could also have kept the other guards (and avoiding moving the helper function) with a pattern guard: `| Just (Piece White _) <- n` (standard since Haskell 2010).

Answer (score 1):

The crucial thing is this: pattern matching works fundamentally different from equality comparison (and is usually much preferrable)!

By pattern matching, you only look at whether a piece data “fits some rough shape you're interested in”. You may completely ignore parts of the data you're *not* interested in, as you tried with `Just (Piece White _)`. Pattern matching is thus generally a “fuzzy operation”.

OTOH, `==` is just an operator ([library-defined function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Eq.html#v:-61--61-)) which takes two values and determines whether they are *exactly equal*.  `Piece White _` is not actually a value, you'd need to give a concrete `PieceType` to fit the `_` gap. And that's what GHC tries to tell you with that message `Found hole ‘_’ with type: PieceType`: if you actually needed to build up a `Square` value, you would need to supply a `PieceType` value. Those typed holes are mighty useful when you're juggling with complex problems: just start out from the outside, e.g. you might start with `n == Piece _ _`, GHC would tell you it expects in the first gap a `PieceColor`, you'd insert `White`, GHC would tell you it expects in the second gap a `PieceType`, etc..

Just, in the `displaySquare` function it doesn't really make sense to actually construct a concrete `Square` value to compare against: what you really want to do is *deconstructing* such values. And that's where pattern matching is much more handy. In fact, I'd write that function as a single big list of clauses:

```
displaySquare (Just (Piece White King))   = '♔'
displaySquare (Just (Piece White Queen))  = '♕'
displaySquare (Just (Piece White Rook))   = '♖'
displaySquare (Just (Piece White Bishop)) = '♗'
displaySquare (Just (Piece White Knight)) = '♘'
displaySquare (Just (Piece White Pawn))   = '♙'
displaySquare (Just (Piece Black pt))
   = toEnum . (+6)  -- Unicode U+2659 WHITE CHESS PAWN
                    --  is followed by BLACK CHESS KING, etc.
      . fromEnum . displaySquare . Just $ Piece White pt
displaySquare Nothing = ' '
```